# Multilevel Model in Matrix Form

Tags: self-study, mixed-model, references, multilevel-analysis, random-effects-model

A two-level model, with one explanatory variable at the individual level $(X)$ and one explanatory variable at the group level $(Z)$ :

$Y_{ij}=\gamma_{00}+\gamma_{10}X_{ij}+\gamma_{01}Z_{j}+\gamma_{11}X_{ij}Z_{j}+u_{0j}+u_{1j}X_{ij}+e_{ij}\tag 1$

correlation between $u_{0j}$ and $u_{1j}$ is $0$ .

The matrix form of a mixed model collects the fixed effects in a vector $\boldsymbol \beta$, and the random effects in a vector $\boldsymbol u$ , and finally the random error term, which is also a random effect factor in the vector $\boldsymbol e$. A formal definition is
$\boldsymbol Y=\boldsymbol X\boldsymbol\beta+\boldsymbol Z\boldsymbol u+\boldsymbol e\tag 2$

with $X$ the known design matrix for fixed effects and $Z$ the known design matrix for random effects .

Now I  want to write down equation (1) in matrix form. But I wonder that **the matrix equation does not capture the entire effect. It is missing the $X_{ij}Z_j$ term.**

Say, in equation (1), I have 3 groups (J=3) and 2 individuals (i=2) in each group so that the total sample size, N=6 .

Then equation (2) will be,

$\boldsymbol Y=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        y_{11}\\
        y_{21}\\
        y_{12}\\
        y_{22}\\
        y_{13}\\
        y_{23}\\
        \end{bmatrix},\quad\quad \boldsymbol e=
        \begin{bmatrix}
        e_{11}\\
        e_{21}\\
         e_{12}\\
        e_{22}\\
         e_{13}\\
        e_{23}\\
        \end{bmatrix}
$
, and is $\boldsymbol\beta=
        \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma_{00} \\
\gamma_{10} \\
\gamma_{01}\\
\gamma_{11}\\
        \end{bmatrix} ?
$

How will be $\boldsymbol X$ , $\boldsymbol Z$ and $\boldsymbol u$ in equation (2) look like ? How can I conform the matrix equation of equation (1) ?

Any help is appreciated. Many thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [Hox & Roberts (2011)](https://books.google.de/books?id=JlhySkysflUC&pg=PR2&dq=hox+roberts&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIhoi5nbqoxwIViesUCh2URgH5#v=onepage&q=hox%20roberts&f=false), they work through an example in matrix notation on pages 6-7. They collect all individual, group, and cross-level terms in $X$.

Comment: @hplieninger Would you like to post your comment as answer. Thank you very much for the link.

Comment: The link , https://books.google.de/books?id=JlhySkysflUC&pg=PR2&dq=hox+roberts&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAGoVChMIhoi5nbqoxwIViesUCh2URgH5#v=onepage&q=hox%20roberts&f=false,  helps a lot. But how did they get *$u_{1j}$math$_{ij}$* ?

Comment: They simply call it $u_{1j}$ (but see their Eq (1.9)).